# Why in the github desktop application after cloned my project i don't see any changes and can't click the Commit to main button?

Tags: github, github-desktop

[image: Changes is empty and can't click the button]

This is a screenshot of my repo in the github.com and i copied the url from Code > HTTPS
Then paste the url to the application url tab but it didn't add any changes files and i can't click the commit button.

[image: Repo on github.com]

On my hard disk in the project folder i created a new folder named it Git and selected this folder when paste the url to the application :

The Git folder was empty now it have some files :

[image: Git folder in my project]

And last a screenshot on my hard disk the project with the Git folder and inside it created a sub folder and inside two files :

[image: The folders on my hard disk]

What am i missing ?

I tried to follow this tutorial in youtube :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpXxcvS-g3g

Comment: Questions about GitHub Desktop need to be tagged with [tag:github-desktop], not [tag:git].

Comment: Did you make any changes?

Comment: @Ethan not yet but i don't see my project in the github.com in my repo. only the reamde file and the ignore file.

Comment: @DanielLip ok. I don't fully understand what you are asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Ethan how do i add/upload my unity project ot the github.com repo ? as you can see in my question in my second screenshot the repo is empty only two files the project is not there.

Comment: @Ethan in github.com in my repo i clicked on Add File then  Upload files and selected my project files and folders on the hard disk but it didn't add the folders and the files inside only the files on the root folder of the project. why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Cut the files (.gitattributes, README.md and .git folder) from the newly created subfolder and paste them into the folder that contains the files that you want to see displayed on the Git desktop. Try to reopen the git desktop and you will see your files.  On your case cut the files from the local path that ends with LineRendered-controller and paste them into the folder Git

Answer (score -1):

To get the files to show up in GH desktop navigate the branch the files were uploaded to then click `fetch origin` then `Pull origin` on the top navbar.